# putting an image and putting a wiki page on top of the image

Tags: sharepoint

I am very new to SharePoint. I want to create a web part that has an image in the background. For this, I went to insert at the top of the SharePoint page. Below is the image:

[image]

I want to insert the image first from the list of parts available in the web part and then I want to select application list so that application list can come on the top of the image. How can I achieve that? or is it possible to put the image first and then put a list on top of it.

any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add custom background image to the list view webpart zone.

Sample demo:

Insert a Content/Script Editor Web Part into the page and insert this code snippet into Web Part.

```
<style type="text/css">
#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2{
    background-image:url(‘Your image url’);
}

</style>
```

[image]

Find the zone id `#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2` by developer tool.

[image]

Comment: how can I put the application list on top of that image.

Comment: You just need add the application list to the page, the background image is added by CSS(demo as above).